# Add watermark in PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

Does anyone knows how to add watermark in [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

I am using this **PDF.js** in my java web application to preview PDF files. But I don't know how add watermark in this PDF.js when previewing.

I have tries the following,

```
        pageView.setWatermark({
            text: 'Confidential',
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            size: 20,
            angle: 45,
            x: 100,
            y: 100
        });
```

But this error occurred saying there is no any **setWatermark** function

```
viewer.js:11677 Unable to initialize viewer TypeError: pageView.setWatermark is not a function
```

how can i add watermark in PDF.js?

Comment: where did `pageView` come from?

Comment: pageView is in **viewer.js** 

`const pageView = new _pdf_page_view.PDFPageView({...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla PDF.js has no ability to Watermark, whatsoever.

See the most recent of many similar statements
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/14366

> That's not a use-case that this library is intended for; note https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js#pdfjs-
> PDF.js is a Portable Document Format (PDF) viewer that is built with HTML5.

In my Humble Opinion, it should keep to that policy, since as shown by number of issues electronic emulation of watermarks (feint image imbedded in the plain paper background) normally cause many PDF data reader usage problems such as bad or poor DDA readability.

So to see at latest count 32 related issues. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+watermark

If you wish to pay for the privilege then use a commercial library such as [Apryse PDF.JS](https://pdfjs.express/documentation/viewer/watermarks) but be aware e-Watermarks are often easier to remove than add.